# When I align 2 links to the right, a horizontal scrollbar becomes visible

Tags: html, css

As seen in the picture below, I floated 2 links to the right.

When I did that a horizontal scrollbar came on the screen.

How can i make it fit the screen?

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*Navigation bar*/

nav {
  background-color: #47476b;
  overflow: auto;
}
nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em;
  background-color: #47476b;
  margin-right: -0.3em;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  <a href="#">Link 4</a>
  <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Include this css:**

```css
nav {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
nav a {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This `width: 100%;` makes the navbar's width in  percentage that will occupy the full width of the screen. And `overflow-x: hidden;` makes all extra space / overflow in x-axis be not visible so it won't render a scrollbar.

Comment: don't know why that margin-right was there,  putting it on 0px fixed the problem. Thx a lot